# What would cause a successful file transfer to have checksums not match?

Tags: ubuntu, checksum

After very large file transfers (this only happens with 10gig+ files) to a specific system, the receiving system would have a mismatched checksum of the file.

The transfer seems to have happened sucessfully, the files match in terms of size to the byte, but the file will be corrupted.  if it was a gzip it would have a crc error, and an md5sum would not match.

This is on the exact same server hardware running Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit.

There are no logs of memory issues, filesystem errors (ran an fsck) or hard drive failure.

any ideas?

Comment: I would start by comparing the two files to figure out what the difference is. It would also help a lot if you posted *how* you were transferring the files (scp, nfs, rsync).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possibilities,  but you need to provide more information.  Such as source and destination system details, file transfer mechanism, and what sort of data.

Comment: I'm gonna throw out a guess and say "FTP, and forgetting to flip the ascii/binary flag while transmitting a file"

Comment: That was my guess as well,   but I thought I would ask the question first.